# What is the name of this sound change, and do we have it in English?

Tags: english, phonology, phonetics, sound-change, persian

I'm a Persian, I'm from Iran, and I speak Farsi.
Here, we have a very strange rule that we turn آ into و in informal conversations.
For example:

```
خانه = house (formal) /kh a ne/
خونه = house (informal) /kh u ne/
```

In other words, we mutate a sound based on formality.

I don't know the name of this phenomenon. And I also wonder if we have something similar in English or not?

Comment: I wonder... would shortening "want to" to "wanna" and "going to" to "gonna" etc. count?

Comment: perhaps "Sire" vs. "Sir"?

Comment: If you said "khune" and someone didn't understand you, and asked you to repeat yourself, would you say "khune" or "khane"?

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim, that has never happened I guess. but in case it happens, my first response would repeating "khune" assuming they have not heard me. I mean it's so understandable that I can't think of "not umderstanding" as the cause of misunderstanding. but after a couple of tries, yeah I would fall back onto "khane"

Comment: Not misunderstanding like they don't know what the word is, but like over a phone and they didn't hear.

Answer (score 8):

The shift of classical Persian ān to ūn is a feature of Tehran dialect (Tehrūnī), and of many other forms of colloquial Persian. It is an example of “labialization”. This phenomenon is widespread in languages of the world; we have it in English when we write “all” but pronounce it like “awl”.

Comment: To be clear for the OP, "awl" isn't an informal pronunciation of "all." It's an example of the same sound shift.

Comment: I have no idea how house "formal or informal" could translate into English.

Is this to do with "house" and "home" or what?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin My guess is that not so much "formal" vs. "informal" as it is "classical" vs. "colloquial".

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I was picturing for example, the /t/ in "most definitely" would be lost in rapid speech, but if you were speaking clearly or in Congress or something, you would pronounce it. If I was speaking clearly, I would still labialize "all," as would most speakers I know (but always happy to see counterexamples).

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin The word for ‘house’ was originally /xɑːne/, which in most standard variants of Modern Persian is now /xɒːne/, with a rounded back vowel. In some dialects, particularly Tehrani, and especially in colloquial registers, /ɒː/ has been raised first to /oː/ and then all the way to /uː/ before nasals, so /xɒːne/ is now /xuːne/, /iɾɒːn/ (Iran) is /iɾuːn/ and /tehɾɒːn/ is /tehɾuːn/. It’s not that they have different formal and informal words for ‘house’, but that the word is one of many that has a more formal and a more colloquial possible pronunciation.

Comment: Since Ablaut is an original feature, it's imaginable that this particular shift was motivated in an original case and later used freely. It's like *Scheune* "barn" in German, yes? \*(s)kew- (cf. *house*) is reconstructed with a labial indeed, and various similar reconstructions exist, and *Hütte* "hut, shed, shag" ~ *Haus* for example fits the in/-formal distinction, insofar *Hütte* is dimunitive as it's just smaller, shaggier (not really cutsie) and thus potentially pejorative, sarcastic or just honestly humble (cf. *Hunnehütte* "dogshed").

Comment: also, Ablaut could mark plurality (man, men). I'm not sure if it always has and Germanic were just most archaic in this respect or what, but this is pretty close to a definite indefinite distinction (do you have fish, the fish?).

Comment: Is "labialization" really the usual term for this? The  change seems to go from an unrounded low back to a rounded high back vowel, so there's clearly more involved than just lip rounding (which "labializaiton" might refer to).

Comment: @vectory There’s no reason to believe that ablaut has anything to do with this. It’s just a vowel gradually narrowing from open to closed, same as has happened in countless languages across the world. Also, _man/men_ is umlaut, not ablaut.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, by the way, I never understood why its called Ablaut. As a native German speaker, it seems to imply the coda, the sound in the *off* (cp. *Abgang*). This is rather meaningless in a monosyllabic environment. However, if the Umlaut was conditioned by terminal voicing begetting vowel harmony, then that's correctly an ablaut phenomenon. Whereas Umlautung describes diphtongs, OHG *furi* > \*fuir, *fuer* > MHG *für*. But sure, my allusion to *house* is mistaken anyway insofar as it's not directly cognate. There seem to be a bunch of indirect house-cognates though.

Comment: Speaking of which, Persian *x-* from PIA \*H (PIE \*Hwes- "to be")! What the h is up with that? There is no reason to think with any certainty that it was a matter of ablaut, but there is some reason, namely Officer Uncertainty, to think about possible reasons for the difference. You saying the difference were arbitrary means you do not want think about it, which is like your own problem, so please keep it too yourself--which is the same argument structure you seem to level against me, fair enough. But yours is the default, implicitly understood, goes without saying. Mine adds a certain idea.

Comment: @vectory Er, no. Umlaut does not “describe diphthongs”. It describes one vowel assimilating, in part or completely, to a different vowel in the following syllable. Ablaut is a very different thing, one whose origin is not well-understood. And vowel changes, which are constantly happening in _all_ languages, do not have to be caused by either. The change from /aː/ to /æː/ – which has occurred in such languages as Danish, Attic Greek, Standard Arabic and northern dialects of Irish – is just that: a vowel change. No specific reason, other than that’s how it happened to go. This is the same.

Comment: @No Name; Azor Ahai; Janus Bahs Jacquet House "formal or informal" will never work in English, “classical" v "colloquial" or what.

What’s lost in rapid but not formal speech is about personal diction, not linguistics.

That the word for ‘house’ was originally /xɑːne/… et al addresses the Question how?

Who thinks /kh a ne/ v /kh u ne/ comparable to "want to" v "wanna" or "going to" v "gonna”, why not explain? 

Words having more formal and more colloquial pronunciations are examples, not Answers.

If “all” and awl” sound different in “average” English, why not explain?

Comment: To whom is it not obvious that if we're comparing "formal" vs. "informal" to "classical" vs. "colloquial", we're on a hiding to nothing. Even in a single language, we'd be on a wild-goose chase. Isn't switching such loose concepts between any two languages almost asking for confusion?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin. Of course, we are talking about what is usually called diglossia. There is a "high" register, normally associated with written texts and a "low" register associated with spontaneous speech. In the case of Persian, the high register emulates the language of classical Persian literature, while the low level encompasses a dialect continuum which developed historically from the Western Middle Iranian languages.

Comment: @fdb Oh, thanks… and you couldn't bring yourself to post that as a helpful Answer because… uh…?

If you want to make a comparison even between "formal" v "informal" or "classical" v "colloquial", let alone "high" and "low" registers why not Post that as an Answer?

At the same time, why not add enough detail to make sense in general English?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: fdb's point about diglossia is peripheral to this question, so should not have been posted as an answer.

Comment: @ColinFine. I am lost.

Comment: @fdb, I thought Robbie was giving you stick for having posted the comment about diglossia as a comment, and thought you should have posted it as an answer. I was pointing out that it would not have been appropriate as an answer. (Though I subsequently noticed that Tomato's answer was, in my view, equally peripheral)

Comment: I almost was giving fdb stick for posting a Comment instead of an Answer but hey! What's peripheral is supposed not to be Posted as either… Still and again, isn't switching such loose concepts between any two languages asking for confusion?

Answer (score 8):

I don't know Persian, however I have some knowledge of linguistics.  The example given seems to be linked to a shift in register (different use of language in different circumstances).  The formal form is 'greater effort'; the informal form is 'lower effort' / more relaxed, which here is a shift from the higher pitched 'a' sound to the lower pitched 'u' sound.

In the example given, this seems to be a semi-generalised rule for this particular sound. I'm not sure if English has similar semi-generalised rules, but something slightly similar would be the general use of contractions. To some people, contractions are a marker of informality and should not be used in highly formal speech or writing.

- 'will not' vs 'won't'
- 'can not' vs 'can't'
- 'should not' vs 'shouldn't' (I avoided using 'shouldn't' in the above paragraph)

In general, contractions are dropping or altering specific sounds, which seems to fit with the original poster's request. As well as contractions, some other examples of shifts in register are:

- 'want to' vs 'wanna'
- 'going to' vs 'gonna'
- 'yes' vs 'yeah'
- 'no' vs 'nah'

You will note that the informal form is often 'less effort' than the formal form.

However, be careful not to label it 'lazy' or 'incorrect'.  Often the formal form is regarded as 'formal' because it is the type of language (dialect) used by the power group in that culture. Formal language is often used as a tool to exclude others from membership in that power group, or to mark out membership / signify access to education / parentage / etc.

Sometimes the use of a differing dialect is deliberate to signify that the speaker refuses to participate in what they see as an unjustified power structure. (Or to signify membership in a different social grouping.)

Answer (score 1):

In Arabic this practice is called "ibdal" (which means conversion) (ابدال).

In Persian the same name is used because:

1. Persian has borrowed so many words from Arabic.
2. Ibdal is also a Quran reading technique in the Muslim world (where 'n' before 'b' turns to 'm'). Since Iran is also a Muslim country they use this name to refer to the technique.

** I know this from a bunch of Iranian friends.

Another example: انبه (Anbeh) which means mango, turns to امبه (Ambeh) in spoken Persian language.

Comment: Changing /n/ to [m] before labials is a completely different thing. That’s **nasal assimilation**, and it’s found in virtually all languages around the world, [including English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/199077).

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm not a linguist, I studied Uyghur and other languages of central Asia for a few years. It sounds like you are describing vowel rounding. Other regional languages such as Uyghur, Kazakh, Turkmen, and others have clear rules for vowel rounding and rounding harmony.

Although vowels in English might be described as rounded or unrounded, it doesn't have the same kind of structures for deciding when a vowel should be rounded or unrounded. For example, words with unrounded vowels don't need to be rounded to become informal, and conjugation won't result in rounded vowels.